generateSqlDelightInterface fails for two databases with the same CREATE statements
I have two databases in my SQLDelight Gradle block:
sqldelight {
    databases {
        create("Database") {
            packageName.set("dev.db")
        }
        create("OtherDatabase") {
            packageName.set("dev.db2")
        }
    }
}

After building, SQLDelight got an error and no /build/sqldelight folder was generated. What is the correct way to generate two files with same table name, same database file name and same package name since I need two different ColumnId (folder platform /android needs ColumnId A, /ios needs ColumnId B)?

Task :shared:generateCommonMainDatabaseInterface FAILED
Compiling with dialect
app.cash.sqldelight.dialects.sqlite_3_18.SqliteDialect
/shared/src/commonMain/sqldelight/dev/db/Tables.sq: (1, 13):
Table already defined with name user 1    CREATE TABLE user(
^^^^ 2        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 3        name TEXT 4    )
/shared/src/commonMain/sqldelight/dev/db2/Tables.sq: (1,
13): Table already defined with name user 1    CREATE TABLE user(
^^^^ 2        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 3        name TEXT 4    )
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.


1: Task failed with an exception.
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':shared:generateCommonMainDatabaseInterface'.
A failure occurred while executing app.cash.sqldelight.gradle.SqlDelightTask$GenerateInterfaces
Generation failed; see the generator error output for details.


2: Task failed with an exception.
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':shared:generateCommonMainOtherDatabaseInterface'.
A failure occurred while executing app.cash.sqldelight.gradle.SqlDelightTask$GenerateInterfaces
Generation failed; see the generator error output for details.
BUILD FAILED in 3s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed

build.gradle:
sqldelight {
    databases {
        create("Database") {
            packageName.set("dev.db")
        }
        create("OtherDatabase") {
            packageName.set("dev.db2")
        }
    }
}

*.sq file:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user(
_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
CATEGORY_ID INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
);

Build system:

SQLDelight 2.0.2
Gradle 8.9
Kotlin 2.0.20
Dialect SQLite


Simple way:
Try using "Rename Column" SQL query to change to the same ColumnId (either on Android or iOS side, run database migration with rename SQL query).
Advanced way:
At "KMP" root project must create two "/module" folders:

/iOsDbMobule:

Define these folders as normal: /iosMain, /commonMain.
Config/setup sqlDelight to generate A.db (include ColumnId AA).


/androidDbModule:

Define these folders as normal: /androidMain, /commonMain.
Config/setup sqlDelight to generate A.db (include ColumnId BB).



After build (run configuration) recheck it's valid (in folder /generate...*.sqldelight). To verify at native project:

iOS side: import *.xcframework from "KMP prj", it will mock to corresponding class/database files (with columId AA).
Android side: import *.aar from "KMP prj", it will mock to corresponding class/database files (with columId BB).


Do not abuse code formatting please.
